# Rails 5 and Postgres - Can I use a "?" in the field name?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am wondering if using a "?" in a field name will cause any problems when using Rails 5 and Postgres?

Example of field name:

want_to_sell?

has_certification?

Comment: Have you tried? Also, why would you *ever* want to do this?

Comment: I am storing answers to questions. For example, Want to sell? is a true, false, so want_to_sell?, seemed more intuitative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, a question mark `?` is invalid in an identifier. The only way you could use that is if you use the dreaded [quoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

```
create table bad_names
(
  "want_to_sell?"      boolean,
  "has_certification?" boolean
);
```

But I **strongly** suggest you do **not** do that.

Quoted identifiers generate so many problems down the line that they are not worth the perceived little advantage of following the naming conventions from a different programming language.